# Given the expression n = p × k + r , (0 ≤ r < k). Find the values ​of p and r when known n and k

Tags: c, if-statement, initialization, declaration, undefined-behavior

I've been trying to do this but I'm getting an error Time Limit Exceeded, please help!

Example of input and exepected output

```
Input#1: 5 2
Output#1: 2 1
```

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        long long n, k, p, r;
        scanf("%lld %lld", &n, &k);
        if (r >= 0 && r < k){
            if (n >= 1){
                p = (n - r) / k;
                r = n / (p * k);
            }
        }
        printf("%lld %lld", p, r);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The variable r is not initialized. So this statement if (r >= 0 && r < k){ invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: `p` must be initialised too with a default value should none of the conditions be true.

Comment: Use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` compiler options if using *gcc* or *clang*, or if using something else figure out how to turn on warnings. It will save you hours and hours of hitting your head against a wall trying to figure out easily avoidable bugs.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but how exactly can you find 2 unknowns in a single equation?

Comment: Get used to *always* check the return value of `scanf` and friends – it returns the number of successfully scanned values, if that doesn't match the number of values that *should* be scanned then some input error occurred.

Comment: Please [edit] and dd some examples of input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `r` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value

```
long long n, k, p, r;
```

So this if statement

```
if (r >= 0 && r < k){
```

at once invokes undefined behavior.

What you need is to include the header

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and to use the function `lldiv` declared in this header that calculates the quotient and the remainder of two numbers.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    long long int n = 100, k = 13;

    lldiv_t result = lldiv( n, k );

    long long int p = result.quot;
    long long int r = result.rem;

    printf( "p = %lld, r = %lld\n", p, r );
}
```

The program output is

```
p = 7, r = 9
```

Or instead of the function you could use the two operators `/` and `%` like

```
p = n / k;
r = n % k;
```

Comment: Could you clarify why `lldiv` is required here? The OP might not be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can take the reference from the code written in python, I first calculate the highest multiple of k (less than `k`) divisible by `n`. It is calculated by the `//` operator in python. Like, `37/5=7.4` but `37//4 gives 7` (floor of 7.4).  Then I calculate `r` and finally prints them

```
# 37 = p*5 + r
# take n=37 and k=5

n,k = map(int,input().split())  # take n,k as input 
p = n//k                        # it will max multiple of k divisible by n
r = n - (p*k)                   # r = 37 - (7*5)
print("p =",p," and r=",r)      # print answer here
```

Comment: Wrong language... Many things that are fine for one language can be done better in another one, see `lldiv` in other answer. Apart from, if a compiler sees `p = n/k; r = n%k;` it might optimise to use a CPU command to calculate both at once, if available – like intel's DIV command.